# What to do when desktop is frozen, but sound and mouse still work

Tags: video, vlc, freeze, .desktop

Sometimes when I double click on a mkv video file, instead of opening vlc the system freezes. Audio continues to run, i can move the mouse, but the rest of the desktop (including the clock) is frozen. I end up resetting my pc, which also means I lose all unsaved data.

Question: What can I do in such a case where I can still move the mouse, but the entire UI is frozen? Is there any way to drop down to terminal? Restart the desktop manager? Any other ideas?

Right now I live in fear from clicking on video files.

Comment: Do any keyboard commands work? What about CTRL-ALT-F1?

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I will try it next time it happens.!

Comment: Edit your question and show me the output of `free -h`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll surely miss them.